# Stack growth or not?

Tags: arrays, stack, mips, mips32

A C function f1 has a local integer array of 100 elements, and it calls another function f2. After complied into MIPS, which of the following statements is true?
(a) When this function is called, the stack will grow exactly 100 bytes.
(b) When this function is called, the stack will grow exactly 400 bytes..
(c) When this function is called, the stack will grow no less than 404 bytes.
(d) None of the above.

My thinking is the answer is D because the function f1 has 100 elements of an integer array, so since each integer uses 4bytes, 100 bytes are needed. We have a lack of information with function f2 however, since f2 could also have an integer array that is stored on the stack.  The fact that we do not know whether function f2 has an integer array AND even if it did, we do not know whether or not that function chose to store the array on the stack, makes me assume D is the correct answer.  It is correct to assume that just because you have a function doesn't mean you will allocate space on the stack for whatever it might contain, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you figure out why answer C is formulated as it is?

Answer (score 1):

In architectures, where return addresses are passed in registers, the 'leaf' function can simply say `br [r15]`. This in turn presupposes that to call leaf function f2, f1 must invoke some instructions that first set the return address to r15 and then call f2. But what happens to the previous content of r15? Where does f1 return to?

Even if MIPS would use stack based storing of return addresses, the same concept applies.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not follow how your explanation relates to the question. Any additional information would be greatly appreciated. I am new to MIPS.

Comment: Let's put this the other way: you have given explanations for answer a and evaded answers b and c without giving any insight why they would be clearly wrong. I'm trying to explain the mechanism in c: why on earth anyone would choose an arbitrary constant of 404 as the size.